# Assistance with Java

Tags: java

please help me with the question below, I'm a beginner at programming trying to get my head around it

```
public class LandVille {
private int[][] land;
private boolean hasHouse;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    LandVille landVille = new LandVille(3, 4);
    landVille.displayLand();
}

// Task A - constructor
LandVille(int numRows, int numColumns) {
    land = new int[numRows][numColumns];
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; ++j) {
            land[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    hasHouse = false;
}

// Task B
public void displayLand() {
    for (int i = 0; i < land.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < land[i].length; ++j) {
            System.out.print(land[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

// Task C
public void clearLand() {
    for (int i = 0; i < land.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < land[i].length; ++j) {
            land[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    hasHouse = false;
}
}
```

From the main method, ask the player for the row and column of the land. The number of rows
and the number of columns should be greater than 0 and less than or equal to 10. If any input is
not correct, show an error message and ask for that input again.
If all inputs are correct, create an object of LandVille class from main method. The row and column
values are passed as the parameter of its constructor.

Comment: Sounds like you need a help with inputs in Java. [This link](https://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class) could help, or even [this one](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-io).

Comment: Please ask a specific question. What does not work the way you intended? And please give your post a meaningful title.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Also, as others have indicated, please write a real title for this - as written, your title really doesn't describe the question.

Comment: Hello all, thanks for your suggestions, I do apologise for inconsistent information, as previously said i  cant understand half of the jargon, hope to update my skills and knowledge..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code to accept the values using `Scanner` class:

```
Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
int row = 0, col = 0;
while(true)
{
    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows:");
    row = ob.nextInt();
    if(row <= 10 && row > 0) break;
    else System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
}
while(true)
{
    System.out.println("Enter the number of columns:");
    col = ob.nextInt();
    if(col <= 10 && col > 0) break;
    else System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
}
LandVille landVille = new LandVille(row, col);
```

The purpose of the while loop:
If the user enters an invalid number, then the loop continues, asking the user to enter again.
If the user enters a **valid** number, then the loop stops, and the program continues.

`ob` is an object of Scanner class, and calling `ob.nextInt()` allows the user to input a number. The links provided in the comments may help to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your request. Below is some code that does what you need.

First, you need to use the object `Scanner` to interact with the user. 
Second, it is better to use the `do ... while` synthax. With it, the user will enter at least one time in the loop before quit it if the provide answer is correct.
Finally, others comments are in the code.

Best regards.

```
/* You need to use the object Scanner to interact with the user */

import java.util.Scanner;


public class LandVille {

private int[][] land;
private boolean hasHouse;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row = 0, col = 0;


    // enter the number of rows
    // loop until you enter the right row (row can be 1-10)

    do {

        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows:");
        row = keyboard.nextInt();

    } while (row > 10 || row <= 0);


    // enter the number of colums
    // loop until you enter the right col (col can be 1-10)

    do {

        System.out.print("Enter the number of columns:");
        col = keyboard.nextInt();

    } while (col > 10 || col <= 0);

    // when the variables (row, col) are correct, then the object LandVille can be created.

    LandVille landVille = new LandVille(row, col);
    landVille.displayLand();
}

// Task A - constructor
LandVille(int numRows, int numColumns) {
    land = new int[numRows][numColumns];
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; ++j) {
            land[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    hasHouse = false;
}

// Task B
public void displayLand() {
    for (int i = 0; i < land.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < land[i].length; ++j) {
            System.out.print(land[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

// Task C
public void clearLand() {
    for (int i = 0; i < land.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < land[i].length; ++j) {
            land[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    hasHouse = false;
}
}
```

Comment: So it's the same as my answer, but just with do while? Granted, the use of the condition is different, but it is over-complicated here.

Comment: Also, the OP wants it **more** than zero, not more than equal to.

Comment: @Coffeehouse Coder: I've provided a new answer because I assume that @Josi don't know the existence of `Scanner` object, and We need to tell him that he needs to import it. And, I think do ... while is more seem to be more profesional/academic.
Best regards.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder: `The number of rows and the number of columns should be greater than 0` => You are right.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder  Thanks for the help guys, really appreciated, Can I use the same scanner objects to create a menu for the same1. Build a house2. Display land3. Clear the land4. Quit

Comment: @Thex Phi Thank you too

Comment: @Josi Yes you can, but I highly recommend you check out the usage of Scanner class and its methods from some tutorial website first.